# How to get conditions in JIRA from transition

Tags: java, jira

I need to get all conditions programmaticaly from Transition in JIRA. Is there any way to do it? My JIRA version is 3.1.3.

Answer (score 0):

3.1.3, that's pretty old so it's pre REST API. I don't think SOAP ever gave that info either. So some kind of screen scrap of the HTML I guess.

Actually, maybe I should step back and ask why you would want that info.

Comment: My work forces me to use this version and I can not change that.